# Wordpress htaccess overwritten with password code

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

These last days I'm finding that the .htaccess file on my website is being overwritten with a code like the following:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "web"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
```

The site is an updated wordpress and with security plugin (ithemes security) that prevents the change of files ...

Any idea what's going on?
Could it be that some plug-in make this change?

Comment: Where are you hosted? Some hosts have an option to password protect sites this way, it's possible you have that option checked in the control panel or something?

Comment: thanks, I will test this...